# Understanding solutions given by transposition

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, adjoint-operators, vector-space-isomorphism

I'm studying solution given by transposition and i would like to clear somethings.

Assume we have the following, let $T < \infty$ and $Q=\Omega \times] 0, T[$, let $\varphi$ given in a Hilbert space $H_1(Q)$ and assume $v \in H_2(Q)$ is solution of the following adjoint problem
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c}
A^{*} v-v^{\prime}=\varphi \text { en } Q , \\
C_{j} v=0 \text { on } \Sigma,\\
v(x, T)=0, \quad x \in \Omega .
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Define the space $X$ as follows
\begin{equation*}
X(Q)=\left\{v \in H_2\mid  v \,\, \text{satisfies the above system} \right\}.
\end{equation*}

So under certain hypothesis on operators $A$ and $C_j$ we have the following result

**Theorem:**
The operator $P^{*}\left(=A^{*}-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)$ is an isomorphism of $X(Q)$ in $H_1(Q)$.

So the idea is now to Transpose the isomorphism to get the following

**Solution given by transposition:** Let $v \rightarrow L(v)$ a continuos anti lineal form on $X(Q)$, then there exist a unique $u \in H_1^{\prime}$ such that $\left\langle u, A^{*} v-v^{\prime}\right\rangle =L(v) \quad \forall v \in X(Q)$. Where $\langle,\rangle$ denothe the bracket duality between $H_1$ and $(H_1)^{\prime}$

Such $u$ it's the solution to the original system.

With this in mind, my questions are the following

1. I would like to know what does mean to "transpose" a linear map, in this case to transpose given isomorphism.
2. Is there any way to know why such form on $X(Q)$ satisfy $\left\langle u, A^{*} v-v^{\prime}\right\rangle =L(v) \quad \forall v \in X(Q)$, I mean I'm not asking for a proof, just for an idea of why or how we got such equality.

Hopefully u can help me and the given information is enough. I wrote everything in terms of a parabolyc system but the idea of transposition works for any kind of systems.